# Wireless on Acer Aspire V3-371 very poor or not working at all. What can I do?

Tags: wireless, acer

I bought an Acer Aspire V3-371 a while ago and istalled Kubuntu 14.04 on it. Most things work fine, just that I often can't connect to wifi.

At home the connection is so bad that I can't use it at all even if I'm sitting right next to the router. However, it works fine when I'm in college where there are many routers and as far as I know it's a public network.
It seems that I can't get a proper connection to the router at home.

Does anyone has any tips or links that could help?

`sudo lspci -nn` gives:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI [8086:1604] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller [8086:160c] (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller [8086:9cb1] (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 [8086:9cba] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller [8086:9ca0] (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 [8086:9c94] (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:9c96] (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller [8086:9ca6] (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9cc3] (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:9c83] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9ca2] (rev 03)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP Thermal Management Controller [8086:9ca4] (rev 03)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 48)
```

`ifconfig` gives:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 20:6a:8a:e2:ce:4c
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
RX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:31021 (31.0 KB) TX bytes:31021 (31.0 KB)

wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 60:57:18:1c:41:20
inet addr:192.168.192.35 Bcast:192.168.192.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::6257:18ff:fe1c:4120/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:7044 (7.0 KB) TX bytes:16003 (16.0 KB)
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I think we might need more hardware information to help you. Please look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then [edit] your question adding the information. Even though in this case your wireless card probably *is* being detected, the same information--about precisely what wireless adapter it is, what driver is being used, etc.--should help in finding the solution here.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I added the output for `lspci -nn` and `ifconfig` does that help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same computer.

You have to edit `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf` (or create it)

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
```

and add this line:

```
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

Then reboot your computer.

Comment: My computer doesn't seem to have ath9 but iwlwifi. any hints on how to get that working?